# Linux: Content of /dev/fb0 not displayed to screen as expected

Tags: c++, ubuntu, vmware, fbdev

I make a small c++ program on Ubuntu 14.04 virtual machine (run by VMWare) to draw some PNG files to framebuffer "/dev/fb0".
I expect content of the PNG files will be displayed on a window on Ubuntu.
But after i run program, VMWare switch to other screen (see the picture1.png below)

[image]

Then, if i make the VMWare full screen, the VMWare switch back to screen of Ubuntu (see the picture2.png below)

[image]

Are there something wrong when run Ubuntu virtual machine by VMWare ?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem.
Basically, content of /dev/fb0 not diplayed on x window but displayed on virtual console.
I have to switch to virtual console by press 'Ctrl + Alt + F1', then run my program. After that my PNG files displayed Ok.